# How to populate JSON data without losing floating precision

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON file. While populating that file into table using `ng-repeat`, i'm not getting the zero after decimal point.

For example, i have the points `6.0`. It is displaying only `6` but not zero. Why this happening? How to solve this? That zero is very important for me as i used that for filtering the data.Kindly someone suggest me how to solve this issue.

```html
<tr ng-repeat="x in filtered=(Results | filter: strSearch)">
  <td>#{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
  <td>{{x.DeadLines.Fall}}</td>
  <td>{{x.GRE}}</td>
  <td>{{x.IELTS}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is the code which i have written. In `Ielts`, 6.0 is displaying as 6. But i want to display as 6.0 itself. But when i use 6.01 or 6.1 its displaying.

```js
$scope.Results = [{
      "Address": "https://grad.ucla.edu/gasaa/deptinfo/deptinfointro.asp",
      "ApplicationFee": 110,
      "DeadlineLink": "https://grad.ucla.edu/gasaa/deptinfo/deptinfointro.asp",
      "GPA": 3.0,
      "GRE": 320,
      "GRE_ETSCode": 4837,
      "IELTS": 6.0;
```

This is my sample JSON file.

Comment: `{{variableName | number}}`. Also you should share some reference code. Just conceptual questions are not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{variableName | number:precision}}`.

Also not sure, but while parsing variable, `6.00` will be considered as integer and not float, hence it is represented as `6` and not `6.00`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uaagz3o2/2/).

```js
function myCtrl($scope){
 $scope.number = [];
  $scope.number.push(6.00);
  
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
   $scope.number.push(Math.random());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h3>No formatting</h3>
    <ul ng-repeat="n in number">
      <li>{{n}}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Formatting </h3>
    <ul ng-repeat="n in number">
      <li>{{n|number:2}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the problem is it is not filtering the data based on 6.0. When i type 6. it only showing the 6.5 list. Even for 7.0 also. Kindly support me in filtering When i type 6.0 it showing nothing even though there is data based on 6.0

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: @Rajesh540 when I asked you to create a Fiddle, I meant a working code which I can simulate and help you.